# PHP MySQL Selecting Multiple Tables Based on Column/Row Value

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, database-design

I am just doing some testing with a few tables that I'm trying to relate together, based on the values of my 'students' table.

Here are the total tables that I have:

> students TABLE

id, name, course_num, msg_num

---

> biology TABLE

id, details, msg_num

> chemistry TABLE

id, details, msg_num

> physics TABLE

id, details, msg_num

---

So I'm trying to select the 'students' table first, and based on the 'course_num' & 'msg_num' values in the 'students' table, it will determine which table is selected out of an array of tables that I have (as shown above, the 'biology', 'chemistry', & 'physics' tables).

The 'students' table looks like this:
[image]

The 'biology' table has data like this:
[image]

The 'chemistry' table looks like this:
[image]

The 'physics' table looks like this:
[image]

So, once again, I'm trying to have it to where if the number in   'course_num' in the 'students' table is set to either '0,1,2' , then it will dynamically select the related table from the array list that I have set up in advance. Here is the exact code that I've tried below, but it is NOT syncing up properly. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here:

```
<div style="position:relative; margin:auto; width:400px; font-family:Poppins; font-size:16px; border:2px solid black; padding:10px; margin-top:100px;">


<?php

include 'db_connect.php';


$selected_courses = array("biology", "chemistry", "physics");



$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM students";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
    $course = $selected_courses[$row1['course_num']];

    $sql2 = "SELECT students.*, $course.*, FROM students, $course
    WHERE students.msg_num = $course.msg_num";

    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();

    echo "STUDENT NAME: ". $row2['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "DETAILS: ". $row2['details'] . "<br>";
    echo "MSG NUM: ". $row2['msg_num'] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}


$conn->close();

?>

</div>
```

Comment: ensure that it is an integer perhaps - `$selected_courses[ (int)$row1['course_num'] ];`?

Comment: Your schema is broken. You should combine the three identical course tables into one, with an additional column to identify the subject. Then your queries can link the students to their courses directly using a `JOIN` and there's no need to select a specific table.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular can you give me an example of what you mean? I'd really like to keep each table separate, then combine them into a queue within 1 main table after selecting them with checkboxes. Maybe you can elaborate on your ideas a little more. Thanks for participating.

Comment: @AaronEsteban The schema is referred to as ManyToMany association and should be like: `students (id, name)`, `courses (id, name)`, `students_courses (student_id, course_id)`. Where `students_courses` determines the courses assigned to each of the students in either direction. EG: `SELECT s.*, c.*, FROM students AS s LEFT JOIN students_courses AS sc ON sc.student_id = s.id LEFT JOIN courses AS c ON c.id = sc.course_id` Your current approach is "risky" by injecting the table name as a "hard-coded" variable and will lead to a fragile design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is basically wrong, and your code includes a nested query which is almost always the wrong way to do things.

Instead of three identical tables with different course data, set up one table and add a `course_num` column. This allows you to `JOIN` your students directly to their details rows, and you can use a single `SELECT` with a `JOIN` to extract the data.

So using your student table and this courseDetails table:

```
CREATE TABLE `courseDetails` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msg_num` int NOT NULL,
  `course_num` int NOT NULL,
  `details` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

You can JOIN on the common columns between the two tables like this:

```
select name, details, s.msg_num 
  from students s 
  join courseDetails d 
    on (s.course_num = d.course_num AND s.msg_num = d.msg_num);
```

To get this output in a single query:

| name | details | msg_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam Smith | Biology Details #0 | 0 |
| John Wright | Chemistry Details #1 | 1 |

From that you can vary the JOIN conditions and use WHERE clauses to create different output as you need, all from the two basic tables.

This simplifies your PHP code to

```
include 'db_connect.php';

$sql1 = "select name, details, s.msg_num from students s join courseDetails d on (s.course_num = d.course_num AND s.msg_num = d.msg_num);";

$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "STUDENT NAME: ". $row1['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "DETAILS: ". $row1['details'] . "<br>";
    echo "MSG NUM: ". $row1['msg_num'] . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Demo:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3cmTkGhEgiBEUZS7dFNvnz/0

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and sample code. I will review your recommendations, test out this particular example, and report back to you right after. Thanks again for your assistance and time.

Comment: Your sample code seems to be running great as far as syncing up the tables go. However, this leads me to the next question in regards to selecting these tables.

Say that I wanted to increment the 'msg_num' and when it reaches the peak 'msg_num' for the selected course ('course_num' and what messages are available within each course), how would I have each student switch over to the next course in the queue after reaching the peak 'msg_num' of each course ('course_num')?

Comment: I currently have the 'msg_num' incrementing from 0 to the max/peak number of what's available within each course's 'msg_num', but I'd like to have the 'msg_num' go back to 0 and switch the student to the next course in the queue using the 'course_num' to increment 1 number up to select the next course in the queue.

I'm sure that you know what I'm saying, but just to make sure, I'll give you an example....

Comment: perpendicular Let's say that I have 10 messages in 'biology', once the 'msg_num' reaches 9 (since we start from 0 in arrays & 9 really represents message 10, of course), then the student will now be moved to, say, 'chemistry' by incrementing the 'course_num' and then having the student start from 'msg_num' 0 to start the cycle over and reiterate once again until each student has successfully passed through each course and each message.

Comment: This is also what I was originally trying to accomplish, learning to travel through each table in an ordered sequence. Anyhow, thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention that this is how I'm incrementing and updating the 'msg_num' to send the next message in the queue. Please see the code below....

Comment: //Increment & UPDATE the msg_num to send the next message in queue
$sql_increment_update = "UPDATE contacts SET msg_num = msg_num + 1";
$result_increment_update = $conn->query($sql_increment_update);

Comment: You can select the number of messages in a course and use a bit of integer arithmetic to increase the message number and course number: `update students s join (select course_num, count(msg_num) as msgCount from courseDetails group by course_num) d on (s.course_num = d.course_num) set s.course_num = s.course_num+((s.msg_num+1) DIV d.msgCount),  s.msg_num = (s.msg_num+1) % d.msgCount  where s.id = 1 ;` (this updates student with `id`=1 only).

Comment: I would like to update ALL students simultaneously via their 'msg_num' and their 'list_num'. Each time the page loads it increments the 'msg_num' for each student and then each student gets moved to the next 'list_num' depending on if the number of messages are capped off on each list. How exactly would the sql statement look to achieve this type of UPDATE? Thanks again.

Comment: Just remove the `WHERE s.id=1` clause to update all students. You'll probably need to add something to handle those students that are on the last `msg_num` of the last`course_num`. You'll have to figure that out in the context of your wider system.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Yeah, I thought that I tried that at first and it wasnt working, but then I realized that I had a typo as well. Anyhow, I really appreciate people like you who take the time to help others. I'll go ahead and mark this as answered and boost up your score a little. Thanks again! ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐

Comment: I hate to revive an old dead thread, especially because you've answered my questions correctly, but I've noticed that there is still a major problem that I've forgotten to point out to you previously.....CONTINUED BELOW.....

Comment: The problem is that each student starts out on a different list ('list_num') and if say a student starts out on number 1 of the list, he/she is able to smoothly transfer to the next list to receive ALL messages ('msg_num') from each list....CONTINUED BELOW....

Comment: BUT the if a student starts somewhere in the middle or end of the list at a higher 'list_num' like 4 and 4 is the end of the lists, then that student is brought to a halt and never gets to receive messages from 'list_num' 1, 2, & 3.

Comment: How would we make sure that each student receives every message from every list regardless of whether they start on a higher list number? Do we need to change the database's table schema once again or do would just build off of the current 'UPDATE' query that you currently have to achieve this? Thanks again for your support.

Comment: @Aaron [so] exists to answer specific questions. As you point out, this question has already been answered, so it's time for a new question. However, bear in mind that we're not involved with your project, so we don't necessarily see the wider picture and how answers we give here might relate to a wider problem.  I suspect that you need to decide what you need to achieve first, then post a new question if you don't make headway on your own. What you're asking here doesn't necessarily need to relate directly to what you've already done. Good luck!